# Segmentation Fault with merge sort function in C coding

Tags: c

I've been working on this code and I believe my logic is correct but it keeps throwing a segmentation fault. I was just hoping to get another set of eyes to help me see what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for your time.

Comment: what parameters do you pass that will invoke the seg-fault?

Comment: Its two sorted arrays and their lengths, and a third array which is empty to merge them.

Comment: I'm asking what two arrays are passed in? e.g. [1,2,3], [4,5,6]

Comment: What is the size of the third array?

Comment: They are both long arrays of strings from an input file that contains names of people that are alphabetically sorted. I have tested this they both work. If its necessary I will post all the names but its kind of a lot to put into one comment.

Comment: The third array is SIZE*2, SIZE is the defined variable I used for array one and two

Comment: Compile wih `gcc -g`, on the commandline do `ulimit -c unlimited` then run it again, which should produce a core dump.  Inspect the core dump using `gdb program-name core*`.  At the prompt, type `bt` (backtrace).  That should at least tell you which line it crashed on.

Comment: It appears that an edit has gone horribly wrong; the code assumed to be attached to the post no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the wrong array subscripts here:

```
else if ((strcmp(*(array2 + i) , *(array1 + j)) < 0)) //compares first position in each array again
```

You are using the `i` subscript with `array2` when it should be `j`. You've swapped the subscripts with `array1` as well.

By the way, do you know you can say `array1[i]` instead of `*(array1 + i)`?

**Edit:**

You have two `if` blocks that test `array1[i]` and `array2[j]` for `NULL` values. I think you need to add a `continue;` to the end of each code block. Otherwise you hit the following `if` statements and pass `NULL` to `strcmp()`.

Do you really need to test for `NULL` when you have `count` parameters that tell how many entries are in each array?

Comment: @silentman45: Did you also fix the `array3[k] = (array1[j]);` assignment below it?

Comment: ya other than that, does the code seem ok I'm kinda new to c so I'm still trying to find out exactly whats throwing the segmentation fault. I tried taking @cdarke's advice but it came out saying no stack so I'm not sure if I did it right, everything else is  working except for this one function.

Comment: This is how I call the method: mergeArrays(array1, count1, array2, count2, array3);

Comment: @silentman45: You code tests for `NULL` values in each array but still calls `strcmp()`, passing `NULL`. This is the probable source of your segfault.

Comment: thanks @Blastfurnace I fixed those if statements but still getting segmentation fault.

Comment: we do need to consider if they are empty or NULL because the arrays are not the same size so once one has been completely moved to the 3rd array the second array will still have values that need to go into 3rd array and we dont wanna go back and look at the 1st array.

Comment: __You know the array sizes because you pass a `count` variable for each one.__ Unless you are putting `NULL` pointers in each array on purpose you don't need to test for `NULL` values.

Comment: Ive cleaned up my code done tons of read through and determined the exact problem is array 3 is not getting filled, or that the error is with printing out the third array

Comment: I've gotten rid of the NUlls as well the logic is sound is there any reason why the points in the first two arrays wouldnt be adding to the thir array so I believe the error must be with lines like array3[k] = (array1[i]); and all similar ones

Comment: He shouldn't have to complete your entire assignment for you (iteratively) as you hack on it to get accepted.  If you really wanted a definitive answer, you'd show a complete, compilable test case that reproduces the crash.

Comment: Ok @RandyHoward would you like the complete code Because I just posted it I'd also appreciate if you dont come on here and act like I'm just looking for answers for some assignment Im trying to figure out the reasoning as well for this segmentation fault. Your negative response doesnt help anyone Now although his information was helpful he never addressed the problem I was having thats why I continuously asked for help. PLZ do not come on here and act like a hot shot programmer cause I'm new to c randy its people like you that give programmers a reputation for being stuck up and anti social.

Comment: I was not 'acting like a hot shot', I was trying to point out that Blastfurnace spent time over an hour and a half long window trying to solve your issue, despite working with an incomplete picture of the problem.  It's not his fault that your original question was too vague to solve the numerous problems in your program.  The point of my comment was that you should probably accept the fact that he tried to answer your question, vague as it was, and in fact found a number of issues for you.  Have the dignity to accept his answer, and if you still have problems, ask another question.

Comment: I have no other questions to ask Randy and you were I am not being rude or mean to blastfurnace I was not eve demanding his answer I was appreciative of everything he said the once If you read the comments I did ask another question the question was if anyone saw any reason why array 3 would not be filled. I'm not just sitting here asking why am I getting a segmentation fault every two seconds. If you cant admit that your rudeness was uncalled for you are trying to be a hot shot.

Comment: My point was simple.  Accept his answer if it helped you.  If you have another question, based upon the results of the changes to your program since then, ask another question.

Comment: I did and I figured it out thanks for nothing Randy your help was useless